# Unable to generate report using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

while generating Junit Report using Eclipse,i get this error .

[junitreport] : Error! Use of the extension element 'redirect' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true.

[junitreport] Failed to process /home/affi/workspace/project1/junit/TESTS-TestSuites.xml

Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with older versions of ant and java version 1.7... See [Ant  fail because of Xalan's (XSLT) secure processing feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240388/ant-junitreport-fail-because-of-xalans-xslt-secure-processing-feature) So far all I see as a solution/work around is to use ant 1.8.3... Not exactly what I'd like to do... Oh well, good luck...